# Getting error while connecting Facebook with R

Tags: r, facebook, api, text-mining

I am trying to use `RFacebook` package and following the tutorial mentioned on this page [link](http://pablobarbera.com/blog/archives/3.html)

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Timeout was reached
```

An solution to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that as Facebook changed their API most functions from this packages don't work any more. That might be the source of your problem.

From [RFacebook Github repository README](https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook/blob/master/README.md) :

> NOTE : the following documentation is outdated, since many functions
>   stopped working when Facebook deprecated version 0.1 of the Graph API.
>   I am working on an updated version that will be up soon. In the
>   meantime, check the documentation of the package for more information
>   about what functions are available.

If you installed the package from CRAN (version 0.3), you could try your luck and install it from Github *via* `devtools` (version 0.4).